Powershell script to Add a user and give full control of two different registry keys
I am trying give a user full control to two registry keys in the script below. The script works for the first registrykey but I don't know how to add a second key into the same script. Do I do another Invoke - command after the first one is done? Basically, copy everything and change the variable to $registrykey2.
    $computerName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the name of the remote computer"
    $username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the username"
    $registryKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ODBC"
    $registrykey2 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC"
    $domain = "domain\$username"
    $permissionType = "FullControl"


    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -ScriptBlock {
    param($registryKey, $domain, $permissionType)
    
    $acl = Get-Acl "$registryKey"
    $permission = $domain, $permissionType, "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"
    $accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule $permission
    $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule)
    Set-Acl "$registryKey" $acl
    } -ArgumentList $registryKey, $domain, $permissionType


probably yes, have you tried adding the second Invoke? Did it work? if not what errors did you get?

You would just add a parameter to your scriptblock for the second key, and then get the ACL for the second key, add the ACR  to it, and set the ACL to the second key within the same Invoke-Command.
That said, I think you are mistaken in how you are doing that. You get the ACL, but then you use $acl.SetAccessRule($accessRule) instead of $acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule), which I'm pretty sure replaces any non-inherited access rules with the one you specify. If there weren't any explicit rules on that key then it's no big deal, or if that was your intent, but I've found that usually people want to add access, not replace it.
$computerName = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the name of the remote computer"
$username = Read-Host -Prompt "Enter the username"
$registryKey = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\ODBC"
$registrykey2 = "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\ODBC"
$domain = "domain\$username"
$permissionType = "FullControl"


Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName -ScriptBlock {
    param($registryKey, $domain, $permissionType, $registrykey2)

    $acl = Get-Acl "$registryKey"
    $permission = $domain, $permissionType, "ContainerInherit,ObjectInherit", "None", "Allow"
    $accessRule = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistryAccessRule $permission
    $acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
    Set-Acl "$registryKey" $acl

    $acl = Get-Acl "$registryKey2"
    $acl.AddAccessRule($accessRule)
    Set-Acl "$registryKey2" $acl

} -ArgumentList $registryKey, $domain, $permissionType, $registrykey2

Since you already defined the access rule you can just reuse that rule, and add it to the second key.

Thank you very much for your input. I was able to get the script working for both keys and I also changed to the Add vs Set.
